How to get list of device names that are available for LVM
I am using lsblk command to get the device names on linux servers. However, I want to find the command that will help me scan the devices and store the results in an array only for devices that are available for LVM
Right now, I am using
lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT | grep disk | awk '{print $1}'



However, this prints all the devices that are available and busy.
I need to print sd* device name that is available (not already in use) to perform LVM steps. I am trying to scan all the available sd* devices at run-time and based on availability mount the filesystems on the available sd* device

This the main point is to identify devices available for LVM, I think this question should be asked at [su].

What are "devices available for lvm"? Aren't all devices available for lvm?

@KamilCuk I need to print sd* device name that is available (not already in use) to perform LVM steps. I am trying to scan all the available sd* devices at run-time and based on availability mount the filesystems on the available sd* device

What are "not already in use" devices? Having a partition counts? Having a partition table counts? Being mounted counts?

@KamilCuk Filesystem mounted on an sd* device will be considered as busy as when you try to create physical partition, it will throw an error message - /dev/sda1 is busy. So the idea is to get list list of all sd* devices which do not have any partition.

You lost me. Devices which do not have any partition, or devices which are not mounted? These are two different conditions. A device may be mounted without any partitions, or a device may have partitions from which zero or more may be mounted. it will throw what is "it"? Specific utilities do check if a device is mounted. But they are these specific utilities. For example, busybox mkfs does not check if a filesystem is mounted and you can happyli format mounted filesystems.

Hi checkout again and i saw your answer to check your available disk is df -h try it and you will see your available mounted disk
If you have other disk you can't see them for first you need to mount your disk in /etc/fstab and you can see your uuid to mount with:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
And mount your disk for first and then see that availability
Have a great day.

I need to print sd* device name that is available (not already in use) to perform LVM steps. I am trying to scan all the available sd* devices at run-time and based on availability mount the filesystems on the available sd* device. These commands do not give me that results.

Bro if it's possible please give back your mines vote of my recent answer i wrote for you how you can see your available disks

After inspecting with comments that the real goal is to:
"How to list all sd* devices without mounted partitions?"
I find it will be hard iterating over output of lsblk. Instead, iterate over devices, and check for mountpoints. Even something simple along:
find /dev -regex "/dev/sd[0-9]+" |
  while IFS= read -r dev; do
     if ! lsblk "$dev" | grep -q '/'; then
        echo "$dev"
     fi
  done

Or like:
find /dev -regex "/dev/sd[0-9]+" |
  while IFS= read -r dev; do
     if ! mount | grep -q "$dev"; then
        echo "$dev"
     fi
  done

You could also see lsblk --json output.
All my devices are used, I do not really have a way to check this code.

If you want too see the available sd* you must to use this command:
ls -l /dev/ | grep -i sd

And if you need to see your uuid to mount your disks in /etc/fstab/ you must to use this command:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

Excuse me for misunderstood, Have a great day.

Hi yes lsblk won't show your available storage but you can use df -hT to see how many percent of your storage is available or it's in use
